# Add horizontal lines, grouped by factor

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot with lines, grouped by the `rank` factor:

```
ggplot(data=res.sum.df, aes(x=i_id, y=success_rate, colour = rank)) +
geom_line(size=1.5, aes(group=rank))
```

[image]

I have additional `data.frame` object which define mean value of the all values within each rank:

```
> res.sum.df.mean
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  rank mean_succes_rate
1    1       0.16666667
2    2       0.13735450
3    3       0.13628500
4    4       0.05797931
```

I would like to add four vertical lines of `yintercept` with these mean values, additionaly **coloured (grouped) according to the existing line legend**.

I tried adding some `aes` argument and other things, but all my combinations failed (**lines are not coloured**):

```
  ggplot(data=res.sum.df, aes(x=i_id, y=success_rate, colour = rank)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, aes(group=rank)) +   
  geom_hline(yintercept = res.sum.df.mean$mean_succes_rate, aes(colour=rank))
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_hline(data = res.sum.df.mean, aes(yintercept = mean_succes_rate, colour=rank))`? (Posted as comment because question lacks example data for testing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the intercepts in the aesthetic mapping:

```
geom_hline(data = res.sum.df.mean, 
           aes(yintercept = mean_succes_rate, colour=rank))
```